# Как сделать переключение меню в сайдбаре?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

у меня есть сайдбар  двумя уровнями. При нажатии на пункт, меню как бы съезжает влево, при нажатии на кнопку назад меню уезжает вправо, и открывается изначальный вариант с пунктами.

https://codepen.io/dganil/pen/RwpdOBj

```js
$('.menu-title').bind('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('.menu-item').find('.menu-hidden').css('transform', 'translate(100%,0,0)')
  $('.menu-wrapper__wrap').css('transform', 'translate3d(-100%,0,0)')
  // transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);

})

$('.menu-toggler-back').bind('click', function() {
  // $(this).parents('.menu-hidden').css('left', '100%')
  $(this).parents('.menu-hidden').css('transform', 'transform: translate3d(100%,0,0)')
  $('.menu-wrapper__wrap').css('transform', 'translate(0)')
})
```

```css
.menu-toggler {
  width: 24px;
}

.menu-toggler svg {
  width: 24px;
}

.menu-wrapper,
.menu-hidden {
  background: white;
  width: 440px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-wrapper__wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-hidden {
  z-index: 101;
  position: absolute;
  /*left: 100%;*/
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="menu-toggler">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 18" id="icon-menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M1 0a1 1 0 100 2h22a1 1 0 100-2H1zM0 9a1 1 0 011-1h22a1 1 0 110 2H1a1 1 0 01-1-1zm0 8a1 1 0 011-1h22a1 1 0 110 2H1a1 1 0 01-1-1z"></path>
        </svg>
    </span>
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <div class="menu-wrapper__wrap">
    <div class="menu-top">
      <span class="menu-toggler">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="icon-arrow-left" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.707 15.707a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-7-7a1 1 0 010-1.414l7-7a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L5.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 010 1.414z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </span> Naomi
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      <p class="menu-title">Item 1</p>
      <div class="menu-hidden">
        <div class="menu-hidden__top">
          <span class="menu-toggler menu-toggler-back">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="icon-arrow-left" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.707 15.707a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-7-7a1 1 0 010-1.414l7-7a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L5.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 010 1.414z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </span> Каталог
        </div>
        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li class="menu-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="menu-list__link">Link 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      <p class="menu-title">Item 2</p>
      <div class="menu-hidden">
        <div class="menu-hidden__top">
          <span class="menu-toggler menu-toggler-back">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="icon-arrow-left" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.707 15.707a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-7-7a1 1 0 010-1.414l7-7a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L5.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 010 1.414z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </span> Каталог
        </div>
        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li class="menu-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="menu-list__link">Link 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      <p class="menu-title">Item 3</p>
      <div class="menu-hidden">
        <div class="menu-hidden__top">
          <span class="menu-toggler menu-toggler-back">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="icon-arrow-left" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.707 15.707a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-7-7a1 1 0 010-1.414l7-7a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L5.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 010 1.414z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </span> Каталог
        </div>
        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li class="menu-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="menu-list__link">Link 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay">
</div>
```

Почему-то меню не работает, всегда при нажатии на пункт, выезжает menu-hidden последнего пункта.

А там их три пункта и у каждого свое меню должно выезжать

Answer (score 0):

У вас блоки с классом `menu-item` находились друг над другом, и блок с `Link 3` находится выше всех, поэтому и видели вы только его.

Ну и других проблем горстка была.

```js
$('.menu-title').bind('click', function() {
  $(this).next('.menu-hidden').addClass('active');
  $('.menu-wrapper__wrap').css('transform', 'translate(-100%,0)');
})

$('.menu-toggler-back').bind('click', function() {
  $(this).parents().find('.menu-hidden').removeClass('active');
  $('.menu-wrapper__wrap').css('transform', 'translate(0)');
})
```

```css
.menu-toggler {
  width: 24px;
}

.menu-toggler svg {
  width: 24px;
}

.menu-wrapper,
.menu-hidden {
  background: white;
  width: 440px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-wrapper__wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.menu-hidden {
  z-index: 101;
  position: absolute;
  /*left: 100%;*/
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.menu-hidden.active {
  z-index: 105;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="menu-toggler">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 18" id="icon-menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M1 0a1 1 0 100 2h22a1 1 0 100-2H1zM0 9a1 1 0 011-1h22a1 1 0 110 2H1a1 1 0 01-1-1zm0 8a1 1 0 011-1h22a1 1 0 110 2H1a1 1 0 01-1-1z"></path>
        </svg>
    </span>
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <div class="menu-wrapper__wrap">
    <div class="menu-top">
      <span class="menu-toggler">
                    <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="icon-arrow-left" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.707 15.707a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-7-7a1 1 0 010-1.414l7-7a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L5.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 010 1.414z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </span> Naomi
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      <p class="menu-title">Item 1</p>
      <div class="menu-hidden">
        <div class="menu-hidden__top">
          <span class="menu-toggler menu-toggler-back">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="icon-arrow-left" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.707 15.707a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-7-7a1 1 0 010-1.414l7-7a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L5.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 010 1.414z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </span> Каталог
        </div>
        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li class="menu-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="menu-list__link">Link 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      <p class="menu-title">Item 2</p>
      <div class="menu-hidden">
        <div class="menu-hidden__top">
          <span class="menu-toggler menu-toggler-back">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="icon-arrow-left" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.707 15.707a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-7-7a1 1 0 010-1.414l7-7a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L5.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 010 1.414z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </span> Каталог
        </div>
        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li class="menu-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="menu-list__link">Link 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      <p class="menu-title">Item 3</p>
      <div class="menu-hidden">
        <div class="menu-hidden__top">
          <span class="menu-toggler menu-toggler-back">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" id="icon-arrow-left" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.707 15.707a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-7-7a1 1 0 010-1.414l7-7a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L5.414 8l6.293 6.293a1 1 0 010 1.414z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </span> Каталог
        </div>
        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li class="menu-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="menu-list__link">Link 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay">
</div>
```